# Dynamic height with scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

i have a window with a scrollviewer in the scrollviewer is a collection of usecontrols that can very from total empty to infinity. i want the height of the window to be fitted to the height of the screen so that it do not overflow, also i would like if no code behind is used because i use a MVVM pattern..

Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="FreePIE.GUI.Shells.CurveSettingsView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="CurveSettingsView" Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="Curves" Grid.Row="0"></ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button x:Name="AddCurve" Width="150" Grid.Row="1">Add new curve</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your `ItemsControl` to take up all available space, and to resize its contents so that no ScrollViewer is needed to see all the items

If that's the case, replace the default `ItemsPanelTemplate` in your `ItemsControl` with a control that stretches to take up all available space, such as a `DockPanel`. The default `ItemsPanelTemplate` is a `StackPanel`, which will grow as much as needed.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Curves" Grid.Row="0">

    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```

If you want all your items the same size, I would suggest using a `UniformGrid` instead of a `DockPanel`, and binding the `Rows` property to the number of items in your collection.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Curves" Grid.Row="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, 
                Path=Items.Count}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Sorry if i was a bit unclear, no i want the window to take up no more then the height of the screen, if the content of the itemscontrol makes the window bigger than the screen then i want the scrollviewer to limit the visible part of the itemscontrol so that all of the window is visible on screen, thanks...